# Write to each table to csv followed by header

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data using BS4 and then write it to CSV. The pattern I am looking to write in CSV is similar to [this website](https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data).

So its more like 1: header 3 then respective table then header3 and table so on...
But I am getting this kind of output:

```
Total rainfall in millimetres for SherkinIsland 
Mean temperature in degrees Celsius for SherkinIsland   
Mean 10cm soil temperature for SherkinIsland at 0900 UTC    
Global Solar Radiation in Joules/cm2 for SherkinIsland  
Potential Evapotranspiration (mm) for SherkinIsland 
Evaporation (mm) for SherkinIsland  
Notes on the Data
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,199.1,67.2,116.6,129.3,93.0,17.2,48.8,62.5,82.1,,,,815.8
2017,66.7,78.5,132.7,14.6,39.2,112.3,89.9,78.6,150.8,115.5,51.9,147.5,1078.2
2016,185.8,113.0,61.5,68.8,59.4,61.5,69.7,111.1,111.1,64.4,43.3,78.3,1027.9
2015,106.6,78.0,88.9,18.5,110.0,77.4,127.0,87.0,121.2,52.8,107.7,292.7,1267.8
mean,132.7,101.4,94.7,73.7,73.7,75.1,78.0,88.3,92.4,127.6,120.1,130.3,1188.0
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,8.2,6.1,5.7,9.2,12.1,15.4,17.1,15.0,13.6,,,,11.4
2017,8.1,8.2,9.2,9.8,12.2,14.0,14.9,14.6,13.5,12.6,9.4,8.1,11.2
2016,8.4,7.0,7.5,8.5,12.0,14.3,14.4,15.2,14.5,12.3,8.0,9.5,11.0
2015,7.5,6.5,7.7,9.4,10.9,12.9,14.2,14.3,13.8,12.3,11.2,10.3,10.9
mean,7.5,7.5,8.4,9.4,11.7,13.9,15.5,15.7,14.3,12.0,9.5,8.0,11.1
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,6.9,4.7,5.1,9.5,13.4,17.3,19.0,16.2,n/a,,,,11.6
2017,7.5,7.9,8.4,10.2,12.9,15.4,16.2,15.3,13.4,12.3,8.5,6.8,11.3
2016,7.4,5.9,6.6,8.5,13.0,15.6,15.8,15.8,14.6,11.8,7.7,8.8,11.0
2015,6.6,5.3,6.8,9.3,11.7,14.5,14.8,14.7,13.1,11.2,10.6,9.6,10.7
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,9023,15831,29709,42026,58669,67070,65526,44784,29711,,,,362349
2017,8345,14868,28307,43479,57060,59325,57794,46218,33526,15375,11157,7084,382538
2016,7262,16452,27956,48481,60218,56262,53776,48503,25866,19137,12859,5660,382432
2015,8882,13475,30056,50190,55679,57207,57047,49551,33798,19483,8962,5121,389451
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,21.8,28.5,34.9,49.9,76.3,98.8,104.6,64.5,42.9,,,,522.2
2017,20.6,25.2,40.5,59.4,75.1,80.5,79.1,63.5,46.3,26.2,38.7,18.7,573.8
2016,20.8,27.3,39.7,61.4,77.3,81.1,73.7,68.6,43.9,39.0,23.5,21.0,577.3
2015,23.5,21.0,38.1,59.8,67.1,73.3,76.1,66.2,53.0,34.4,25.6,24.1,562.2
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,30.5,41.0,55.4,81.0,116.3,143.1,147.9,96.8,64.3,,,,776.3
2017,27.1,37.8,64.0,88.6,117.8,127.9,122.2,97.5,71.3,39.2,46.4,24.6,864.4
2016,28.7,41.0,61.1,96.8,118.9,122.4,112.7,104.8,64.3,52.8,30.3,26.7,860.5
2015,32.7,31.1,60.5,95.8,113.2,115.7,120.8,101.4,75.9,47.2,35.1,32.8,862.2
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a

Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Total
2018,226,262,303,188,115,38,12,30,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
2017,228,206,195,170,105,55,34,37,63,90,183,230,1596
2016,220,247,247,210,112,44,44,28,41,99,226,185,1702
2015,247,253,243,182,143,82,48,46,57,100,130,162,1693
```

My source code is :

```
import time
from os import getcwd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

import time, re
import csv
import uuid


class metEiren():
   def __init__(self):
       print("hurray33")
       global downloadDir
       downloadDir = ""

       fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
       fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
       fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
       fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
       fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

       options = Options()
       options.add_argument("--headless")
       global driver
       driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp,firefox_options=options)
       driver.get("https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data")
       verificationErrors = []
       accept_next_alert = True
   def scrap(self):

       driver.get("https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data")
       driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
       wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
       link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sherkin Island")))
       link.click()
       time.sleep(2)
       uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
       filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
       soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
       headerList = []
       tableContentList = []
       for h in soup.find_all('h3'):
           print(h.text)
           headerList.append(h.text)
       for table in soup.find_all('table'):
           for row in table.find_all('tr'):
               list_of_cells = []
               for hd in row.find_all(['th','td']):
                   list_of_cells.append(hd.text.strip())
               tableContentList.append(list_of_cells)
       with open(filname, 'w', newline='') as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=',',lineterminator='\n')
           length1 = len(headerList)
           length2 = len(tableContentList)

           for i in range(len(headerList)):
               writer.writerows([headerList[i].strip(',').split(',')])
               writer.writerows(tableContentList[s] for s in range (len(tableContentList)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   obj = metEiren()
   obj.scrap()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: It seams that you have successfully scraped the data in its proper order. Can you clarify how it should be written to the csv? What is your desired output?

Comment: It only needs some re-ordering apparently. Can you show a sample of how your `headerList` and `tableContentList` look? I think there might be a small bug in your last `for` loop where you are writing to csv.

Comment: @Ajax1234 yeah , i have scraped it successfully but while writing to csv , i am not able to create file in this format https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data. Which means headerlist has **h3** in it and tablecontentlist **available table**. Writing format should be **h3 --> th --> td --> h3-->above next table --> th --> td and so on**

Comment: @panktijk you can see the output on this url https://codeshare.io/G70M7j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a list of tables rather than appending all of the information into a single list. Then you can use `zip()` to take a single header and table at a time to write it to your output CSV file. This is a better approach than trying to use `range()`.

```
import time
from os import getcwd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas


import time, re
import csv
import uuid


class metEiren():
    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        downloadDir = ""

        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        global driver
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp,firefox_options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data")
        verificationErrors = []
        accept_next_alert = True

    def scrape(self):
        driver.get("https://www.met.ie/climate/available-data/monthly-data")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sherkin Island")))
        link.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
        filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        headerList = []

        for h in soup.find_all('h3'):
            print(h.text)
            headerList.append(h.text.strip('\t'))

        tables = []

        for table in soup.find_all('table'):
            tableContentList = []

            for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                list_of_cells = []
                for hd in row.find_all(['th','td']):
                    list_of_cells.append(hd.text.strip())

                # Only append a row if it non-empty
                if len(list_of_cells):
                    tableContentList.append(list_of_cells)

            tables.append(tableContentList)

        with open(filname, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=',', lineterminator='\n')

            for header, table in zip(headerList, tables):
                writer.writerow([header])
                writer.writerows(table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = metEiren()
    obj.scrape()
```

This would then give you an output looking like:

```
Total rainfall in millimetres for SherkinIsland
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,199.1,67.2,116.6,129.3,93.0,17.2,48.8,62.5,82.1,,,,815.8
2017,66.7,78.5,132.7,14.6,39.2,112.3,89.9,78.6,150.8,115.5,51.9,147.5,1078.2
2016,185.8,113.0,61.5,68.8,59.4,61.5,69.7,111.1,111.1,64.4,43.3,78.3,1027.9
2015,106.6,78.0,88.9,18.5,110.0,77.4,127.0,87.0,121.2,52.8,107.7,292.7,1267.8
mean,132.7,101.4,94.7,73.7,73.7,75.1,78.0,88.3,92.4,127.6,120.1,130.3,1188.0
Mean temperature in degrees Celsius for SherkinIsland
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,8.2,6.1,5.7,9.2,12.1,15.4,17.1,15.0,13.6,,,,11.4
2017,8.1,8.2,9.2,9.8,12.2,14.0,14.9,14.6,13.5,12.6,9.4,8.1,11.2
2016,8.4,7.0,7.5,8.5,12.0,14.3,14.4,15.2,14.5,12.3,8.0,9.5,11.0
2015,7.5,6.5,7.7,9.4,10.9,12.9,14.2,14.3,13.8,12.3,11.2,10.3,10.9
mean,7.5,7.5,8.4,9.4,11.7,13.9,15.5,15.7,14.3,12.0,9.5,8.0,11.1
Mean 10cm soil temperature for SherkinIsland at 0900 UTC
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,6.9,4.7,5.1,9.5,13.4,17.3,19.0,16.2,n/a,,,,11.6
2017,7.5,7.9,8.4,10.2,12.9,15.4,16.2,15.3,13.4,12.3,8.5,6.8,11.3
2016,7.4,5.9,6.6,8.5,13.0,15.6,15.8,15.8,14.6,11.8,7.7,8.8,11.0
2015,6.6,5.3,6.8,9.3,11.7,14.5,14.8,14.7,13.1,11.2,10.6,9.6,10.7
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Global Solar Radiation in Joules/cm2 for SherkinIsland
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,9023,15831,29709,42026,58669,67070,65526,44784,29711,,,,362349
2017,8345,14868,28307,43479,57060,59325,57794,46218,33526,15375,11157,7084,382538
2016,7262,16452,27956,48481,60218,56262,53776,48503,25866,19137,12859,5660,382432
2015,8882,13475,30056,50190,55679,57207,57047,49551,33798,19483,8962,5121,389451
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Potential Evapotranspiration (mm) for SherkinIsland
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,21.8,28.5,34.9,49.9,76.3,98.8,104.6,64.5,42.9,,,,522.2
2017,20.6,25.2,40.5,59.4,75.1,80.5,79.1,63.5,46.3,26.2,38.7,18.7,573.8
2016,20.8,27.3,39.7,61.4,77.3,81.1,73.7,68.6,43.9,39.0,23.5,21.0,577.3
2015,23.5,21.0,38.1,59.8,67.1,73.3,76.1,66.2,53.0,34.4,25.6,24.1,562.2
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Evaporation (mm) for SherkinIsland
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
2018,30.5,41.0,55.4,81.0,116.3,143.1,147.9,96.8,64.3,,,,776.3
2017,27.1,37.8,64.0,88.6,117.8,127.9,122.2,97.5,71.3,39.2,46.4,24.6,864.4
2016,28.7,41.0,61.1,96.8,118.9,122.4,112.7,104.8,64.3,52.8,30.3,26.7,860.5
2015,32.7,31.1,60.5,95.8,113.2,115.7,120.8,101.4,75.9,47.2,35.1,32.8,862.2
mean,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a
Notes on the Data
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Total
2018,226,262,303,188,115,38,12,30,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
2017,228,206,195,170,105,55,34,37,63,90,183,230,1596
2016,220,247,247,210,112,44,44,28,41,99,226,185,1702
2015,247,253,243,182,143,82,48,46,57,100,130,162,1693
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesnn't help. I am getting something like this Total rainfall in millimetres for SherkinIsland
Y,e,a,r
J,a,n
F,e,b
M,a,r
A,p,r
M,a,y
J,u,n
J,u,l
A,u,g
S,e,p
O,c,t
N,o,v
D,e,c
A,n,n,u,a,l
Mean temperature in degrees Celsius for SherkinIsland
2,0,1,8
1,9,9,.,1
6,7,.,2
1,1,6,.,6
1,2,9,.,3
9,3,.,0
1,7,.,2
4,8,.,8
6,2,.,5
8,2,.,1

the code is here : https://codeshare.io/G70M7j

Comment: I copy pasted the exactly first, it wrote nothing but a empty file. I thought you put something for to do , check this link now, it looks as your code https://codeshare.io/G70M7j

Comment: The reason is the tables list you are iterating in zip loop is empty

Comment: If have copy/pasted it again, please retry.

Comment: tables [] was not being appended. it works now Thank you for your help